# SQL constraint check based on foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have several tables in a database and I'm trying to stablish a slightly complex constraint for some of them.

The issue involves mainly four tables:

- A "main" table, with a primary key `id` that can be referenced.
- Two intermediate tables (let's call them "a" and "b"), each with their own `id`, and each with a column referencing (as a `foreign key`) to `main.id`.
- A "final" table, with its own `id`, and with two columns referencing to `a` and `b` respectively.

In the "final" table, the elements referenced from the "a" and "b" tables need to reference to the same entry in "main".

A simplified definition of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `main_table` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -- other fields, indexes, etc
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `main_ref` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `main` (`main_ref`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`main_ref`) REFERENCES `main_table` (`id`)
    -- other fields, indexes, etc
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `main_ref` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `main` (`main_ref`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`main_ref`) REFERENCES `main_table` (`id`)
    -- other fields, indexes, etc
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE `final` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ref_a` INT NOT NULL,
    `ref_b` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `a` (`ref_a`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`ref_a`) REFERENCES `table_a` (`id`),
    INDEX `b` (`ref_b`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`ref_b`) REFERENCES `table_b` (`id`)
    -- other fields, indexes, etc
    -- The `main_ref` value in the entries referenced by `ref_a` and `ref_b` should match!!
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Both the UI and the backend code should already make invalid entries impossible to happen, but this project will eventually involve additional apps connecting to the same database, so I'd prefer the DB engine to take care of as much of the data integrity checks as possible.

Also, it's worth mentioning that, at the current stage of development, adding new columns and/or indexes is perfectly fine.

The information is there, all I'm missing is a way to tell the engine what needs to be checked. I suspect generated virtual columns and `CHECK` constraints may help, but after looking at several sources (including the MariaDB and MySQL documentations and some web searches) I can't find the way to do it.

I'm running MariaDB 10.2.5 on Fedora 25 (x86_64 arch). In case it's relevant, the backend code is written in Perl (v5.24.1) and connects to the database using the `DBI` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (business logic) can't be handled at the `SCHEMA` constraint level, but through either `TRIGGERS` or `STORED PROCEDURES`.

Stored Procedure would validate (again) and allow INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE

Triggers will invalidate if Business Logic is not followed.

**Personal taste** , leave the business logic to the display and back end. Maintaining it in the DB is very hard and error prone and inflexible to changes. But I hear you about external apps that will *m*uck things up ... Hence offer an API as opposed to direct DB manipulations

Comment: Still have to decide which approach to take, but your answer summarizes everything I needed to know regarding SQL, so I'm marking it as good. Thx-